# Error while starting JBoss EAP 6.2 when using Http11NioProtocol

Tags: java, websocket, jboss7.x

I'm developing a web application using JBoss EAP 6.2. Now I want to enable websocket support in JBoss.

After googling around, I found out that I have to change the configuration (standalone.xml) to use the Http11NioProtocol:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.5" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
  <configuration>
    <jsp-configuration source-vm="1.7" target-vm="1.7" x-powered-by="false"/>
  </configuration>

  <!-- Old configuration
  <connector name="http" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" executor="http-executor"/>
  -->

  <!-- New configuration -->
  <connector name="http" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" executor="http-executor"/>

  ...
</subsystem>
```

But now when I try to start the jboss server, I got the following error message:

```
2014-10-23 08:12:12,977 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-localhost/127.0.0.1:80
2014-10-23 08:12:13,072 ERROR [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003044: Threadpool JMX registration failed: javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character ':' in value part of property
  at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
  at javax.management.ObjectName.<init>(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol.start(Http11NioProtocol.java:132) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1051) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.as.web.WebConnectorService.start(WebConnectorService.java:359) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
  at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.4.GA-redhat-1.jar:1.0.4.GA-redhat-1]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
```

Has anybody an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like a bug in JBoss EAP 6.2 which is fixed in JBoss EAP 6.3

For more details:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1036197